# How to display selected items in list component?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a Array Collection which contains around 10 items and i have assigned this arraycollection to list component as dataprovider. Is there anyway that i can display only the first 5 items in the list component without removing remaining 5 items from array collection.

Comment: Do you want to display the first five and be able to scroll through the others, or do you really *only* want the first five?

Comment: i wanted to display only first five..

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the ArrayCollection in another ArrayCollection and then apply a filter function to the first one. That way, your original collection will not be affected by the filter.